# Replace selected values of one column with median value of another column but with condition

Tags: pandas, python-3.7

[image]

So, I hope you know the famous Titanic question. This is what I did so far by learning the tutorial. Now I want to replace NaN values of column: `Age` with median values of part of `Age` column. But the selected part should have a certain value for "Title"

For example, I want to replace NaN of Age where Title="Mr", so the median value for "Mr" would be filled in missing places which also has Title=="Mr".

I tried this:

```
for val in data["Title"].unique():
    median_age = data.loc[data.Title == val, "Age"].median()
    data.loc[data.Title == val, "Age"].fillna(median_age, inplace=True)
```

But still Age shows up as `NaN`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `combine_first` to fill NaN. I have no column `Title` from my dataset but it's the same:

```
df['Age'] = df['Age'].combine_first(df.groupby('Sex')['Age'].transform('median'))
```

Comment: I created the Title column from Name column extracting the title part in the name so the Age can be filled with specific median for the title. Anyway your solution worked like a charm thanks